# Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 video playback lags / stutters

Tags: video, lag

Since some weeks (I didn't use the video playback on this machine for quite a while), I experience lagging/stuttering while playing videos, regardless if it is in a browser or in Ubuntu videos, only in VLC is the result more or less satisfying...

The problem is that the video (not the audio) pauses at a completely random point, sometimes for a fraction of a second, sometimes for a whole second or even more. The problem happened at some point while was using Ubuntu 16.04, I hoped an upgrade to 18.04 may bring it back to normal, well.. It didn't.

I have a **intel i5-6200U cpu with HD Graphics 520 and 8G RAM** installed. Problem happens while using the laptop screen.

Wen i run intel_gpu_top the highest usage never exceeds 25%.

I have reinstalled **xserver-xorg-video-intel & xserver-xorg-core** and  **libgl1-mesa-glx & libgl1-mesa-dri** as well as **ubuntu-restricted-extras**.

Do you have any idea where this new feature could have emerged from?

Answer (score 1):

I think your hardware is new and powerful enough to play video well, but my experience is that standard Ubuntu can have problems anyway.

I suggest that you try the following workarounds.

- Try Ubuntu *live* booted from USB or DVD (to get a system, that is not affected by something that you have installed/modified in your installed system). You can try both 16.04.x LTS and 18.04 LTS. If you start from 16.04.1 LTS, your installed system will stay with the xenial kernel series (4.4) and its kernel drivers, which might play video better than your current system.
- Try Ubuntu community flavours with lighter desktop environments *live*. They will play video better than standard Ubuntu,

  - Lubuntu
  - Ubuntu Budgie
  - Ubuntu MATE
  - Xubuntu
- If you find a version or flavour, that plays video better and you like it generally, install it to replace your current system.